# Criptografar senhas de bancos no arquivo conf

Tags: php

Possuo um sistema em PHP com um arquivo config.php a onde são armazenados as senhas dos banco, o problema e que essas senhas que são armazenadas  nesse arquivo esta de maneira muito exposta gostaria saber uma maneira mais segura de armazenar estas senhas

segue abaixo uma parte do codigo:

```html
define ("TIPO_BANCO", "pgsql"); #Tipo de banco utilizado ex: pgsql  
define ("LOCALHOST", "localhost");
define ("PORTA", "5432");
define ("BANCO", "teste1");
define ("USUARIO", "teste1");
define ("SENHA", "teste1");


define ("LOCALHOSTCG","localhost");
define ("PORTACG", "5432");
define ("BANCOCG", "teste2");
define ("USUARIOCG", "teste2");
define ("SENHACG", "teste2");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não vou falar que não é possível mas pense da seguinte maneira. Para ter acesso a esse arquivo é preciso ter acesso ao servidor, se uma pessoa não autorizada já esta dentro do seu servidor, provavelmente consegue acessar seu banco mesmo sem esse arquivo de configuração.

Outro ponto que deve ser levado em consideração, para criptografar os dados você precisaria de um algoritmo de ida e volta, ou seja, que possa ser encriptado e depois decriptado, senão nunca vai conseguir acessar o banco.

Nesse ponto você pode estar pensando ser uma boa ideia, mas infelizmente, vai apenas ter o mesmo problema, por que a chave de encriptação vai ficar exposta, já que você vai precisar dela para decriptar e conectar no banco, do mesmo jeito que o arquivo de configuração e com ela vai ser possível decriptar os dados do banco. Basicamente é a mesma coisa de fechar um cofre e deixar um bilhete na porta falando onde esta a senha.

Espero ter ajudado de algum modo.

Answer (score 1):

Gomes, tive duvidas semelhantes quando estava montando meu site/servidor.

Mesmo que criptografemos o arquivo de configuração, em outro lugar do nosso php teríamos que colocar a senha para acessar o arquivo.

As recomendações de segurança que encontrei são:
(obs.: elas valem para PHP-FPM com nginx no linux, não até que ponto se aplicam a outros sistemas)

1. Colocar o arquivo "antes" da pasta root do servidor web, mas ainda acessível pelo processo php. Ex: Se o root da página for "/var/www/html" colocar seu arquivo de configuração em "/var/www/" ou outra pasta. Assim, mesmo se alguém conseguir listar seus arquivos através do servidor web, o arquivo com as senhas estará fora de alcance.
2. Remover todas as permissões de "grupo" e "outros" deste arquivo de configuração.
3. Alterar o dono do arquivo para o mesmo usuário que executa o PHP-FPM.

Assim nos aproximamos do modo como o linux armazena chaves privadas do SSH. Somente o usuario que executa o PHP-FPM ou o usuário root conseguem acessar este arquivo.

Espero ter ajudado em alguma coisa.